# maximal independent set on grid graph proof

Tags: algorithms, graphs, np-hard, approximation

I'm trying to figure out proof of maximum independent set from: [this link](https://stanford.edu/%7Erezab/classes/cme305/W16/Midterm/probsession_soln.pdf). (1b part).

And I'm bit confused why exactly sum of $w(v)$ is less than or equal to sum of $w(v')$.
Shouldn't it be other way around? As we define $v'$ if it is in $T$ and is in $S$
[image: proof]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As we define v′ if it is in T and is in S

I think you're misinterpreting the definition of $v$:

> For each $v \in T$, define $v'=v$ if $v\in S$ or as its neighbor in $S$ otherwise

$v'$ is *always defined*; it's just a question of *what* it's defined to be. The above definition means that, if $v \in S$, $v'$ is defined to be $v$, and if $v \notin S$, $v'$ is defined to be $v$'s greater-or-equal-weight neighbour in $S$ (the existence of which was established in part 1a). Then $w(v) \le w(v')$ for each $v \in T$ by construction.

(This is the only way I see to parse the definition that makes grammatical sense, though I think it could be worded better, to prevent people reading "define $v'=v$ if $v\in S$" as a "parenthesised unit".)

Comment: Makes sense now. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome :)